# Static import works, but dynamic import of same module fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, es6-modules, esbuild

I have a small bit of frontend code that is tested by Mocha. In relevant part, it looks like this:

```
export const functionUnderTest = async () => {
  const module = require('./index');
};
```

I need to change the `require` to an `import`. I started with a dynamic import:

```
export const functionUnderTest = async () => {
  const module = await import('./index');
};
```

The dynamic import works fine when bundling this code for the client. But when tested in Mocha, it fails with `Cannot find module`. However, if I import `index` at the top it works:

```
import * as index from './index'
export const functionUnderTest = async () => {
  const module = index
};
```

It feels quite bizarre for the static import to work but the dynamic import to fail. I would expect the module resolution process is the same for both. I'm running the test as follows:

`npx mocha -r esbuild-runner/register test/test_index.js`

Note that the function under test and index are Typescript, so we're dependent on `esbuild` to provide real-time transpilation.